# Materialize Tabs Anchor Links with Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, materialize

**Hi everyone**

I'm making a Web App, using AngularJS and MaterializeCSS for the Frontend, everything was working good until i used a Materialize component called Tabs. When i was looking for errors, i realized that the error is anchor link in tabs. Angular identifies href="#link" like a route, but Materialize uses for id selector. I don't know what to do, and i'll appreciate any help

```
    <!-- Begin Tabs-->
<div class="section white">
    <div class="container tab-container z-depth-5">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
            <div class="center tab-header white-text">
                <h1>Pro Players</h1>
            </div>
          <ul class="tabs">
            <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#top">Top Mundial</a></li>
            <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#NA">Norte América</a></li>
            <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#LATAM">Latino América</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="top" class="col s12 tab-div">
            <h1 class="">Mejores jugadores del mundo..</h1>
            <h2>Norte América</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="NA" class="col s12 tab-div">
            <h1 class="">Mejores jugadores de NA..</h1>
            <h2>Norte América</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="LATAM" class="col s12 tab-div">
            <h1 class="">Mejores jugadores latinos..</h1>
            <h2>Latino América</h2>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Tabs-->
```

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this problem using `ng-show`

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab col s3" ng-click="currentTab = 'Top'"><a ng-class="{'active':currentTab == 'Top'}"  >Top Mundial</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3" ng-click="currentTab = 'NA'"><a ng-class="{'active':currentTab == 'NA'}">Norte América</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3" ng-click="currentTab = 'LATAM'"><a ng-class="{'active':currentTab == 'LATAM'}">Latino América</a></li>
</ul>

<div ng-show="currentTab == 'top'" class="col s12 tab-div">
    <h1 class="">Mejores jugadores del mundo..</h1>
    <h2>Norte América</h2>
</div>
<div ng-show="currentTab =='NA'" class="col s12 tab-div">
    <h1 class="">Mejores jugadores de NA..</h1>
    <h2>Norte América</h2>
</div>
<div ng-show="currentTab == 'LATAM'" class="col s12 tab-div">
    <h1 class="">Mejores jugadores latinos..</h1>
    <h2>Latino América</h2>
</div>
```

js

```
$scope.currentTab = 'TOP';
```

**OR**

you can use `data-target` instead of `href`

```
data-target="#idName"
```

Comment: Sorry but, i tried both, and nothing works, when i tried first option, tabs are no longer clickables, and in the second option, i still having the same problem

Comment: add ng-click in 'li'

Comment: and don't forget to add ng-class

Comment: can add some width and height to li tag

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding anchor tag , you can try adding ng-click in list tag and on ng-click you can change the route or maybe something like *location.hash="LATAM".*

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I just solved the problem by debugging materialize's tabs.js plugin. Now I can switch tabs using ng-click and the animations work smoothly. Here's how you can do it:

1. Download this file
   https://cdn.rawgit.com/Dogfalo/materialize/master/dist/js/materialize.js
2. Go to the tabs.js part of the plugin (lines 1301-1464). Replace that with the jsbin javascript file here:
   https://jsbin.com/nokepaqage/1/edit?html,js,output
3. Set up your routes.
4. In your root controller, set up the prototype `$scope.page = {}`.
5. In your child conroller, for each page, write `$scope.page.id = 'your-title'};`
6. Use ng-class in each `.tabs li a` like so: `ng-class="{active: page.id==='yourPage'}"`.
7. In each `.tabs li a`, set up an ng-click `ng-click="go('/news')`
8. In your root controller, pass in `$location` (see my jsbin) and create the `go` function (see jsbin).

This worked for me! Let me know if you have any question/problems!